# Density of Brownian motion with drift given correlated noise

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

From what I understand drifted Brownian motion as an SDE in one dimension has a normal distribution. In two dimensions the SDE

\begin{align}
dX_t = \mu_x X_t + \sigma_x dW^x_t \\
dY_t = \mu_y Y_t + \sigma_y dW^y_t,
\end{align}
would follow the bivariate normal distribution, from the definition of independence $p(x,y) = p(x)p(y)$.

My question is how would we derive the density function that would arise if we had correlated noise/Wiener processes $W^x$ and $W^y$?

Can it still be the bivariate normal distribution when the processes are not independent? If not, how would you derive/explain this?

Comment: Do you actually know how to derive the result in the one-dimensional setting?

Comment: @Tobsn , I don't understand your question. Do you mean a two-dimensional dBM system? If so yes I do when the noise is independent.

Comment: As you said, the laws of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes in one dimension are Gaussian. But do you know why? If not, than you should probably try to understand that before approaching higher dimensions.

Comment: From what i understand because the noise model is a standard normal random variable. This is not my problem. I am interested in finding out what if these variables are correlated. How does this correlation affect the density of the problem in two-dimensions. @Tobsn

Comment: "From what i understand because the noise model is a standard normal random variable. This is not my problem." No offense, but exactely this is your problem. You try to understand the high dimensional setting, without even knowing why things work out in one dimension. If you actually knew how to prove that statement in 1d, from that you could quite easily infer the answer to your question on your own. Likewise, since apparently you don't even understand the 1d setting, I doubt that you could actually appreciate an answer.

Comment: I understand how things work in one dimension, otherwise, I would ask. " The process is a linear transformation of Gaussian random variables, and therefore itself must be Gaussian."    As the WIki page says. I am just unaware of how to treat the density in two dimensions when the noise is correlated. No offence but you are assuming my question and what I know about the problem. If I am wrong about something tell me I am wrong, there is no need to be pretentious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an $n$-dimensional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process
\begin{equation}
dX_{t}=AX_{t}dt+\sqrt{C}dB_{t}, \quad X_{0}=x
\end{equation}
with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (which is $\operatorname{diag}(\mu_{x},\mu_{y})$ in your case) and correlation matrix $\sqrt{C}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ solutions are given by
\begin{equation}
X_{t}=e^{tA}x+\int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)A}\sqrt{C}dB_{s}
\end{equation}
from which it follows by some linear algebra and standard properties of Ito-Integrals that $X_{t}$ is $\mathcal{N}(e^{tA}x,Q_{t})$ normally distributed, where
\begin{equation}
Q_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}e^{sA}Ce^{sA^{*}}ds.
\end{equation}