# Solving mean and noise in Ornstein--Uhlenbeck process independently

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the multivariate Ornstein--Uhlenbeck process (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process):

$$ dx_t = - \beta x_t dt + \sigma dW_t$$

where $\beta$ and $\sigma$ are constant  $d \times d$ matrices. I would like to solve the OU process by first solving for the mean and then for the deviation of the mean. According to wiki, given a deterministic $x_0$, the mean is simply $\mu(x_t) = \exp(-\beta t) x_0$. The difference between mean and the SDE should then be $x_t - \mu(x_t) = \exp(-\beta) \sigma \int_0^t \exp(t-t') dW_{t'}$. The last missing piece is how to compute $\int_0^t \exp(t-t') dW_{t'}$. Is this analytically solvable?

It seems that in the univariate case $\int_0^t f(t') dW_{t'} = \mathcal{N}(0, \int_0^t f(t')^2 dt') $(https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57066/integration-over-function-of-wiener-process). However, I have a multivariate Brownian motion. Does the result simply extend to a multivariate normal distribution with zero mean and covariance matrix with all diagonal entries $\int_0^t f(t')^2 dt'$ and off-diagonal entries being 0?

Comment: Yes, the result generalizes to involve $\sigma \sigma^T$. but you should be clear: you're not "solving" that integral, you're evaluating an ensemble average of that integral. The value the integral takes on depends on the realization of the noise $dW_t$. There is no unique solution. I suggest Gardiner (1983) "Handbook of Stochastic Methods" section 4.4.6.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I do not want to "solve" the SDE but rather compute a sample of the SDE. What do you mean the result generalized to involve $\sigma \sigma^T$? So $x_t - \mu(x_t)$ is not $\exp(-\beta) \sigma \mathcal{N}(0, \int_0^t f(t')^2 dt')$?

Comment: The Wiener process is a mathematical idealization that you can't really represent with any analytical formula (besides its correlation functions -- also mathematically idealizations tho in that they are Dirac functions). If you want to compute the approximate path of a single noise sample, I suggest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method . Otherwise, the moments and probability distributions across possible realizations of the noise do have analytical representations, even if the individual samples do not.

Comment: It seems to me you want to calculate moments, as you're nearly writing the formula for  $\langle \exp \Big[\int f(t') dW_{t'}\Big] \rangle$ (notice the averaging brackets... this is an average over realizations of the noise). This quantity is not involved with computing a single sample of the SDE.

Comment: I actually just realized that I made a mistake, the difference should be $x(t) - \mu(x_t) = \int_0^t \exp(-\beta (t - t')) \sigma dW_{t'}$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134219/density-of-brownian-motion-with-drift-given-correlated-noise/4135444#4135444